# How to split string contains same pattern

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have problems during splitting string in java. I have

```
String test="if x=7 else if x=6 else if x>5 else"
String leftPart ="if"
String rightPart="else"
```

guys any idea how to split from **if to else** and add an array list or string array x=7, x=6 and x>5.

Actually, I want to do this

```
ArrayList<String>ValueArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    ValueArray =[x=7,x=6,x>5];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `String#split`:

```
String[] tokens = test.split( "\\s*(?:if|else)\\s*" );
```

**PS:** You will get empty strings in output array that you will have to discard.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact answers, i have add removing white space: split("\\sw*(?:IF|ELSE)\\sw*"). Thanks lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
ArrayList<String> list_array = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] string_array = test.split("else");

for(int i = 0; i < string_array.length; i++){
     list_array.add((string_array[i].replace("if ","")).trim());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `String#replaceAll` and `String#split`

```
String s  = "if x=7 else if x=6 else if x>5 else";
String[] parts = s.replaceAll("\\s*(?:if|else)\\s*", "").split("(?<=\\d)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output

```
[x=7, x=6, x>5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand your question. But whatever you are trying to do can be accomplished by using split with regular expresions and zero-width positive lookahead. for example:

```
String test="if x=7 else if x=6 else if x>5 else";

String[] pieces = test.split("(?=else)");

for(int i =0; i< pieces.length; i++){
    System.out.println(pieces[i]);
}
```

output:

```
if x=7 
else if x=6 
else if x>5 
else
```

syntax: split("(?=  what_you_want_to_split_using   )");